# acer aspire 1 wont start

Tags: bios

acer aspire 1 with ubuntu 12.04,was windows XP. had battery problem (would not start on fully charged battery) windows bios update solved problem but pc not been used for some time is there a bios update i can use with ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the laptop can boot, you can use it with Ubuntu.